# Search Engine Friendly URL (SEF/SEO)

Tags: php, url

I want friendly URL names converted to:

Tom's Fish & Chips
Slug: tom-fish-and-Chips

1-2-3 Pizza
slug: 1-2-3-Pizza

Here a function:

```
<?php

function urlTitle($title) {
    $title = preg_replace("/(.*?)([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)(.*?)/", "$2", $title);
    $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
    $title = strtolower($title);
    return $title;
}

echo urlTitle("Tom's Fish & Chips");
echo "<br />";
echo urlTitle("1-2-3 Pizza");

?>
```

The behaviour of the above function is *almost* what I want, since I get:

```
toms-fish--chips
123-pizza
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: My question, the function did not return as expected friendly url. How to solve this problem?  (tom-fish--chips should be tom-fish-and-chips)

Comment: I guess the question is: **please give me a working solution**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function seo($input){
    $input = str_replace(array("'", "-"), "", $input); //remove single quote and dash
    $input = mb_convert_case($input, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8"); //convert to lowercase
    $input = preg_replace("#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+#", "-", $input); //replace everything non an with dashes
    $input = preg_replace("#(-){2,}#", "$1", $input); //replace multiple dashes with one
    $input = trim($input, "-"); //trim dashes from beginning and end of string if any
    return $input; //voila
}
```

Second preg_replace replaces multiple dashes with one.

Examples:

```
echo seo("Tom's Fish & Chips"); //toms-fish-chips
echo seo("1-2-3 Pizza"); //123-pizza
```

Comment: You don't need the second regex, because the first already takes care of the case of consecutive non-alphanum chars.

Comment: It is pretty much needed... `toms-fish--chips` > `toms-fish-chips`

Comment: No it's not, because `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` will match `SPACE AND SPACE` and replace them with a single `-`. You have a `+` in your regex after the `]`. So `tom's fish & chips` will become `tom-s-fish-chips` right away.

Comment: I get tom-s-fish-chips instead of toms-fish-chips

Comment: I don't understand, it will match everything non alphanumeric, if you have `   ` it will replace it with `---`, second regexp does cleanup `---` > `-`, and trim, well trims excess `-`...

Comment: Tom's Fish & Chips become tom-s-fish-chips which should be toms-fish-chips

Comment: @user622378 It does now, check it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following to strip multiple spaces:

```
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title);
```

The following to convert the &:

```
$title = str_replace('&', 'and', $title);
```

and you should include the dash in your first regular expression:

```
$title = preg_replace("/(.*?)([A-Za-z0-9-\s]*)(.*?)/", "$2", $title);
```

Comment: thank you, dash in first regular expression dont seem to work.

Comment: Adding the dash to the list of "allowed characters" in the preg_replace will avoid something like "1-2-3 Pizza" to be converted into "123 pizza" rather than "1-2-3 Pizza" (which is what I think you want).

Answer (score 2):

Put this in **before** the regex:

```
$title = str_replace ('&', 'and', $title);
```

If you are working with accented characters, you want to convert them to us-ascii before the regex, not to loose them (`á` will become `a`, `ő` will become `o` etc.):

```
$title = iconv ("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $title);
```

Also your RegEx can be streamlined a bit. This will change consecutive non-alphanumeric chars into a single '-'.

```
$title = preg_replace ("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "-", $title);
```

Also you don't want your title to start or end with a `-`. The following regex will remove them:

```
$title = trim ($title, '-');
```

Comment: +1 Good answer! Especially the replacement of `&` and the `iconv` transliteration. As an alternative to the last `preg_replace` you could also simply use `trim( $title, '-' )`.

Answer (score 0):

Webarto's version is perfect. I thought maybe this version could be useful to someone because it takes different things into consideration, such as transliteration, changing `&` to `-and-`, and entity decoding ... these things depend on how the data is stored in the db, etc. Note that this also assumes a UTF-8 environment :)

```php
function seo( $str )
{
    $str = strip_tags($str); // tags out, just in case
    $str = html_entity_decode($str,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); // entities to text
    $str = strtolower($str); // lowercase
    $str = str_replace('&', ' and ', $str); // & to and
    $str = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str); // transliterate
    $str = preg_replace('/[\s]/', '-', $str); // space to dash
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '', $str); // only alphanumeric and dash
    $str = preg_replace('#(-){2,}#', '$1', $str); // 2+ dashes to 1
    $str = trim($str, '-'); // no dashes at beginning or end
    return $str;
}
```